# Highlight all Rows using a different color for each unique Row ID

Tags: excel, highlight

I am working with tables of data in Excel such as this...

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | Jack | Texas |
| 88 | Joe | Arizona |
| 93 | Jill | Kansas |
| 99 | April | Baltimore |
| 101 | Horace | Chicago |
| 101 | Gil | Nevada |
| 102 | Bert | Florida |
| 103 | Ernie | Denver |
| 110 | Will | Reno |
| 110 | Peter | Idaho |

The number of rows in the table will not be known in advance.

Is it possible to use some Excel wizardry to achieve this...

1. Highlight all Rows using a different color for each unique Row ID.
2. No rows with different IDs may have the same color.
3. If some IDs exist only once they too get their own different color.
4. I will not know in advance how many rows there may be.

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: "All rows with the same ID should have the same color" do you mean the same color for all items with the same id, or for each one of rows with the the same ID a different color? For example for rows with ID: 88, 101, 110 red, or for 88, red1, 101 red2, 110 red3. For the first case there is a solution using conditional formatting, but I don't think there is a way in Excel for the second case, unless using VBA

Comment: Thanks David. I mean the second case. Every different row ID must have a different color. More than one row can have the same color only if all those rows have the same ID. I was thinking VBA would be needed but how to get a variable number of different colors...

Comment: Share a big enough list (array of integers) of the colors and the code you have tried. Use light colors.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% I fully understand all the conditions, and if it can be implemented using Conditional Formatting. The following is a solution for a variable number of rows and using the following color convention:

1. **Rule 1**: Color1 (grey with bold) for the header.
2. **Rule 2**: Color2 (red back ground) for all duplicated values
3. **Rule 3**: Color3 (green background) for all unique values

Using conditional formatting, **the first rule has to be the first one**.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Here the formula and the range for each rule:

| Rule | Formula | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `=A1<>""` | `A1:C1` |
| 2 | `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1` | `A:C` |
| 3 | `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)=1` | `A:C` |

Comment: Thanks David. I meant your Case 2 in your comment above. I guess VBA is needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that uses VBA. I hacked it together from a bunch of googling so no doubt it is filled with bad coding practices, nonetheless it seems to work.

My solution uses a pre-defined dictionary of just 10 different colors to apply to the row backgrounds. Another dictionary keeps track of what colors have been assigned to a particular row_id and re-uses that color for all rows with the same row_id. If there are more than 10 different rows ids it loops back and re-uses colors as you can see in the screenshot below.

```
Sub AssignColors()

' Range picker variables
Dim xTitleId As Variant
Dim myRow As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

' Dictionary variables
' To use the Dictionary you need to first add the reference.
' Select Tools->References from the Visual Basic menu.
' Find Microsoft Scripting Runtime in the list and place a check in the box beside it.
Dim ID_Val As Variant
' Dictionary to hold the colors you want to use in your table
Dim my_colors_dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
' Dictionary to hold all possible colors
Dim all_colors_dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
' Position of next color to take from the all possible colors dictionary
Dim pos As Variant
pos = 1

' If I don't include this I get an error at myRow.Pattern below
On Error Resume Next

' Populate the all_colours_dict
all_colours_dict.Add 1, RGB(238, 146, 146)
all_colours_dict.Add 2, RGB(172, 248, 47)
all_colours_dict.Add 3, RGB(228, 181, 255)
all_colours_dict.Add 4, RGB(217, 253, 172)
all_colours_dict.Add 5, RGB(100, 212, 253)
all_colours_dict.Add 6, RGB(52, 245, 14)
all_colours_dict.Add 7, RGB(249, 189, 58)
all_colours_dict.Add 8, RGB(36, 255, 205)
all_colours_dict.Add 9, RGB(239, 208, 165)
all_colours_dict.Add 10, RGB(250, 248, 28)

xTitleId = "Range Picker"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    For Each myRow In WorkRng.Rows

        ' Get the ID of this row
        ID_Val = Cells(myRow.Row, 1).Value
        
        If my_colors_dict.Exists(ID_Val) Then   
            ' Add this color to the row with this ID
            myRow.Pattern = xlSolid
            myRow.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            myRow.Interior.Color = my_colors_dict(ID_Val)
        Else
            ' If we already used up all the colors from the all_colors_dict then loop back to the first one
            If pos > 10 Then
                pos = 1
            End If
            
            ' Add this ID and the next color from the all_colors_dict TO the my_colors_dict
            my_colours_dict.Add ID_Val, all_colors_dict(pos)
                
            ' Add this color to the row with this ID
            myRow.Pattern = xlSolid
            myRow.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            myRow.Interior.Color = my_colors_dict(ID_Val)
            
            ' Increment the 'pos' pointer to the next color in all_colors_dict
            pos = pos + 1
    
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

[image] [image]

**Some issues**

1. If I don't include the `On Error Resume Next` I get an error at
   myRow.Pattern below, `Object doesn't support this property or method`. Don't know why.
2. Initially I converted the RGB values to
   decimal but the colors were coming out differently.  E.g:
   `all_colors_dict.Add 1, 15635090` Vs `all_colors_dict.Add 1, RGB(238,146,146)`

**Another Approach**

Initially I had a fancy way to auto-generate colors and I used just one dictionary to keep track of what colors were already assigned to a row_id so that color would be re-used for all rows with the same row_id. The code that loops through each row was like this:

```
For Each myRow In WorkRng.Rows

    ' Get the ID of this row
    ID_Val = Cells(myRow.Row, 1).Value
    
    If dict.Exists(ID_Val) Then
        ' Add this color to the row with this ID
        myRow.Pattern = xlSolid
        myRow.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        myRow.Interior.Color = dict(ID_Val)
    Else
        ' Create a color for the row with this ID
        xRed = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(173, 172)
        xGreen = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(220, 255)
        xBlue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(207, 255)
        
        ' Add this ID and RGB color to the dictionary
        dict.Add ID_Val, VBA.RGB(xRed, xGreen, xBlue)
        
        ' Add this colour to the row with this ID
        myRow.Pattern = xlSolid
        myRow.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        myRow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(xRed, xGreen, xBlue)

    End If

Next
```

In the end I didn't go with that approach because the randomly generated colors were not differentiating the rows enough from one another. Instead I spent ages curating a fixed list of colors that make the row highlighting stand out better however in tables with many different row ids colors get re-used for different row ids. I don't know a good solution to that.

Hopefully this helps someone or any improvements welcome.